# What does <=> operator mean, sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators

I came accross the sql query where the `<=>` operator is put. What does <=> operator mean?

```
SELECT STR_ID, TEX_TEXT AS STR_DES_TEXT, IF( EXISTS( SELECT * FROM SEARCH_TREE AS SEARCH_TREE2 WHERE       SEARCH_TREE2.STR_ID_PARENT <=> SEARCH_TREE.STR_ID LIMIT 1 ), 1, 0) AS DESCENDANTS FROM SEARCH_TREE
```

This sql is of MySQL type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, [read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

> <=> is a NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality
>   comparison like the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both
>   operands are NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Null safe equal operator,it returns 1 if boths operands are null.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to